# Ideal Concept for Excel Lookup - Using High and Low Values to define ZIpCode Ranges which pertain to Territories

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two tabs, one is "sales detail" which contains a field named "sales zipcode". The "sales territory" tab has a range of zipcodes and the corresponding "Sales Territory ID"

```
Zipcode Low        Zipcode High       Sales Territory ID

10000              19999                    15

20000              24999                    20

25000              33999                    22
```

ETC ETC

How can I write a formula for the Sales Territory ID based on the Zipcode?

For instance

```
Zipcode  Sales Territory ID

02348        =???       

23485

23433
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using a `VLOOKUP` but with the `range_lookup` value set to `TRUE`:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Sales Detail'!$A$2:$C$4,3,TRUE)
```

This assumes that your `Sales Detail` data range starts at `A2`. Also, you would need to make sure that your data is sorted in ascending order so that the `VLOOKUP` behaves properly. When you set the property to `TRUE`, it doesn't need to find a direct match - it looks for the highest value that is still less than your target.

Also, as @barryhoudini mentions, you can accomplish the same thing using the `LOOKUP` formula, which by default matches the largest value that is less than or equal to the target. Barry's formula:

```
=LOOKUP(A2,'Sales Detail'!$A$2:$C$4)
```

Comment: Note that LOOKUP can also do the same, i.e. `=LOOKUP(A2,'Sales Detail'!$A$2:$C$4)`

Comment: @barryhoudini You are the one who opened my eyes to `LOOKUP` a few weeks ago - I need to start thinking about it more :)

Comment: Can you implement a cell function to determine the appropriate territory with a series of consecutive ranges of zipcodes, formatted to be 5 digits? Meaning with the data available limited to the hi and low of the range rather than each discrete value being listed in a table?

Comment: @RichardPullman Hmm, that should be what this is doing. Note that we used the `TRUE` argument to `VLOOKUP` which does *not* require a direct match. Therefore you could look up a value like `23485` (from your question) and it would match the row `20000 - 24999` (this is the same thing as suggested by J.T. Grimes in the other answer). Am I misunderstanding the question (probably :) ).

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, let me try this out I'll see how this works!

Comment: This is accurate, use true (approximate match) if you include a series of continuous ascending ranges. Also, this approach doesn't require ranges to be contiguous.

Answer (score 2):

VLOOKUP will do exactly what you want.  The function parameters are `VLOOKUP( value, table_array, index_number, [not_exact_match] )`.  If you pass TRUE (or 1) for not_exact_match, VLOOKUP picks up the largest value which is less than the value parameter.

In your case, make sure the table is sorted by Zipcode Low and then your function is = VLOOKUP(ZipcodeCell,$SalesTerritoryRange, 3,1).